# IndexOutOfRangeException when reading in a field from an Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb, oledbdatareader

I'm having trouble reading values into a list from an Access Database. The values look like this:
Field is called EventDistance
Values are
77
77
77
77
55
112
45
46

My code looks like this:

```
 private void StartSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT Time.AthleteID, Athlete.AthleteName,
                              Time.EventTime, Event.EventDistance 
                              FROM Event INNER JOIN 
                                   (Athlete INNER JOIN [Time] 
                                    ON Athlete.[AthleteID] = Time[AthleteID]) 
                                    ON Event.[EventID] = Time.[EventID];";

        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
        Command.Connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();
        List<PaceCalculator> Distancelist = new List<PaceCalculator>();
        while (Reader.Read())
               {
                   pace.Distance = (int)Reader["Event.EventDistance"];
                   Distancelist.Add(pace);
               }
```

And its throwing IndexOutOfRanceException was unhandled for Event.EventDistance. There are only 8 integers to be read in, but there must be room for my data to expand. How do I make it so it just reads in the integers without throwing an index error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a query like

```sql
SELECT Table1.Column1, Table2.Column2 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ...
```

the resulting columns in the OleDbDataReader are (usually) just named "Column1" and "Column2", so to reference them you just need to use

```sql
reader["Column1"]
```

not

```sql
reader["Table1.Column1"]
```

You are getting an IndexOutOfRange exception because there is no column in the reader named "Event.EventDistance".

Comment: Thank you so much... I have been stressing over this so much, but its solved my error. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source code of the OleDbDataReader for the indexer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbDataReader.cs,202) that gets a string as input parameter and then follow the code, you will notice that the string passed to the indexer is searched between the field names available and, if not found, an IndexOutOfRange exception is thrown.

In your query, there is no field named `"Event.EventDistance"`.
There is a field named `EventDistance` (the tablename should be stripped away from the Reader indexer.

But you have also another problem, your loop add repeatedly the same `PaceCalculator` instance to the list.
So in every loop you set the EventDistance to the same PaceCalculator instance and add it again and again to the list. At the end of the loop the list is full of elements that points to the same PaceCalculator instance and this instance has the value of the last record read.

You could fix this problem moving the creation of the instance inside the loop

```
   List<PaceCalculator> Distancelist = new List<PaceCalculator>();
   while (Reader.Read())
   {
       PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();
       pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
       Distancelist.Add(pace);
   }
```